# Motionlayout file is too big

Tags: android, android-animation, android-motionlayout

I am using Motionlayout to animate a header and a bunch of other view on a fragmnt. But it turned out that XML file has already 700 lines of code and a high potential to continue increasing.
I'd like to know if it is possible to extract some of this logic to another file, to keep it more readable? Something like we do for layout with  tag.

Answer (score 0):

Multi file support is coming in 2.1.

But in the mean time...

1. Make sure you use derived Constraints to have only the views you are changing in each ConstraintSet.
2. Use Sectioned Constraints to reduce the number of attributes you need to use.(See below)
3. Design you layout so that you are manipulating very few Views and the other views are constrained to them.

**Sectioned Constraints**

Normally (And the gui creates) a single Constraint with all attributes you need in it.

```
 <Constraint
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        motion:transitionPathRotate="0"
         />
```

This will replace all of the layout & transform attributes from the parent.
This could be written using Sectioned Constraints

```
 <Constraint android:id="@id/view">
     <Layout
        android:layout_width="90dp"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        motion:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        motion:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" />
     <Motion
        motion:transitionPathRotate="0" />
     <Transform ... />
     <CustomAttribute .../>
     <PropertySet ... />
</Constraint>
```

This way you only have to add the sections you need to override.

Comment: Yah I am using derived and sectioned constraints already, but thanks for the update with the Multi-file support is coming in 2.1.